# Delphi TChart - How to get a series index from x,y mouse coordinates without clicking on it

Tags: delphi, indexing, mouse, series, teechart

I´m writing a new method fired at "OnEndDrag" Event of a TChart standard on Delphi XE7.

I need to know which series the object was dragged to, to perform some actions on a dataset linked to it.

I´m getting the correct xy positions with the event "OnDragOver" and the series gets correctly highlihghted when I drag over it.

Any clues ?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Addenddum:I can´t use anything related to mouse click, since I´m already dragging an object to the TChart Object;

Comment: Perhaps you could use method CalcClickedPart (http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomChart.CalcClickedPart.html) which allows you to get information about which TeeChart component is below the mouse pointer. Another method that could be usefull to you is GetCursorValueIndex (http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TChartSeries.GetCursorValueIndex.html) of specific series which returns index value of the closest series point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I keep getting index 0, no matter whitch series I drag the object to. I have tried the two methods you mentioned, but no success at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop your series list and call Clicked function as follows:

```
var SeriesIndex: Integer;
begin
  for SeriesIndex:=0 to AChart.SeriesCount-1 do
  begin
    if AChart[SeriesIndex].Clicked(X, Y)>-1 then
       //do whatever with AChart[SeriesIndex]
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is what I´ve done before posting this thread. I keep geting index 0 no matter to which series I drag the object. Perhaps because the series was not clicked. For this reason I have mentioned that I can´t use anything related to MouseClick. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Gee, My bad. I was under the impression that I should work with the "Clicked(x,y)" value, and I should work with the loop index instead. Thanks

Comment: The `Clicked` function returns the `ValueIndex` of the point at the given X,Y position. It returns `-1` if no point is at that position.

Answer (score 0):

The "AChart[SeriesIndex].Clicked(X, Y)" method solves the problem. I realized that I was using the return value of the method, instead of using the loop index.